# Postman: send a POST request with query string

Tags: json, postman

I'm trying to send a POST request where the body looks something like this:

```
GUID=abc&Sum=100
```

Usually the system sends that body, but I'm trying to debug and was wondering what is the correct way to send it in Postman? I did try to append the query string to the end of the url but it wasn't received at the backend.

I know that I can "translate" it to proper JSON format and send, but is there a way to send it as raw query string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question isn't clear, you need to send as the server expect it

Comment: Hello, the server expects parameters

Comment: Did you tried to put parameters in x-www-form-urlencoded format?

Comment: `I did try to append the query string to the end of the url but it wasn't received at the backend.` Oh the server received it, that's for certain. But whatever framework your server is written in needs to know how to access it correctly. Post your server code.

Comment: how did you send in postman also add that screen shot or full url format you used

Comment: You should say: what is your server side and route that